# Webpack Extract Text Plugin: how to test for specific file and extract to separate output?

Tags: webpack, extract-text-plugin, extracttextwebpackplugin

The normal way to use the Webpack Extract Text Plugin is as follows:

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    // ...
  },
  output: {
    // ...
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      // ...
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    // ...
    new ExtractTextPlugin('path/to/style.css')
  ]
}
```

This of course works well.

**The issue I'm facing is when trying to test for different path patterns, and outputting to different locations.**

In my case, I'm trying to:

- Test for paths ending with "_base.scss", and output them to "main/base.css"
- Test for paths ending with ".scss" (so all scss files), and output them to "example/style.css"

Based on my understanding from [the documentation](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin), the following should work, but it doesn't.

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')

const allSCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('example/style.css')
const baseSCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('main/base.css')

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    // ...
  },
  output: {
    // ...
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      // ...
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: allSCSS.extract({
        fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        })
      },
      {
        test: /_base\.scss$/,
        use: baseSCSS.extract({
        fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        })
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    // ...
    allSCSS,
    baseSCSS
  ]
}
```

When I run this, all I get as output is the 'example/style.css' with all the styles, but not the 'main/base.css'.

Can anyone explain the correct way to do this please?

Answer (score 0):

Please make following changes in your webpack config::

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    // ...
  },
  output: {
    // ...
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      // ...
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
       loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "sass-loader")
      },

    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    // ...
     new ExtractTextPlugin("style.css")
  ]
}
```

Install style-loader and sass-loader first. and you don't need to make different css files.

**EDITED** Please do the following changes to generate these two css files:

```
const allSCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('all.css')
const baseSCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('base.css')
```

With that configuration in place, two separate CSS files: all.css and base.css will be generated.

Let me know if it doesn't resolve your issue.

Comment: Sorry, I might have misled you by not showing what was the variable that I passed to the extract method - I have amended the code now showing the object literal. To clarify, I know how to set up the Extract Text Plugin, and it works well, but I'm trying to do something different to the usual setup here: I'm trying to test for different patterns, and extract to different files.

Comment: @LiranH I have edited  my ans I hope this would help you

Comment: that's not the solution, but thanks for trying. I've actually just managed to solve it - will post my solution now.

Comment: Glad to know about this, How did you manage to solve it ? Please enlighten me

Comment: Update: I later realised that my solution was not reliable. I never managed to figure this out, and eventually gave up on it.